# Firebase database - read followers posts on user's timeline

Tags: ios, swift, database, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to do basic social app using `Firebase` - each user has user's he follows and on his timeline he can see their post.

I'm using `fanout` technique described [here](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2015/10/client-side-fan-out-for-data-consistency_73.html)

After this my data structure for `user1` looks like this (it contains both - his followings and timeline):

```
{
  "timeline": {
    "user2": {
      "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
        "text": "I love emojis!",
        "date": "2016-09-01"
      },
      "-K-zOrt9a8Asdczaq23G": {
        "text": "Second post!",
        "date": "2016-09-03"
      }
    },
    "user3": {
      "-K-zOrtjiCGe7tgRk8DG": {
        "text": "Post 3",
        "date": "2016-09-02"
      }
    }
  },
  "followers": {
    "user2": true,
    "user3": true
  }
}
```

The problem I have is - I don't know how to read user1 timeline with all posts from all users mixed and ordered by time. I was reading about querying and filtering from [Firebase doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/lists-of-data#sorting_and_filtering_data) but I am not able to figure out the proper way to do it.

I'm developing on iOS platform but I should have no problem with other Firebase solutions as long as they are supported on Apple platform.

Comment: You can save all the date in epoch time and then use the sorting technique 'orderBy' which the firebase SDK provides to get ordered results

Comment: @firecast I'm not sure what do you mean by 'epoch time'. Any example or answer would be great.

Comment: Epoch time is basically the number of seconds passed from 1 Jan 1970 upto the current time. You can get the current epoch time in swift using `NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970`. This is a number so can be ordered by more easily in firebase rather that having a string date format.

Comment: @firecast sure, I know it. The problem is, even if I have timestamp in date field, I don't know how Firebase sorting query should looks like.

Comment: The firebase doc [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#sort_data) explains how you can do sorting with an example almost similar to something you are trying. You'l have to use `orderByChild` like in the example